# aspx.designer isn't finding my controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm having a problem with my designer file for an aspx page. Every time I try to define a script manager, or update panel, or any asp control like so...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
```

The aspx.designer file errors out and I get 'Type.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is not defined, pointing to the script manager, or for that matter any other control. Update panel ect ect.

I've tried deleteing the designer file to no avail. Please help!

Comment: Please provide the actual error you see.

Comment: I did. The error is Type System.web.ui.scriptManager is not defined.

Comment: Close - your question shows `'Type.Web.UI.ScriptManager' is not defined`. When you're showing an error message, it's vital that you copy it in exactly as it is, including case and punctuation - helps with searching, and avoids any ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [ScriptManager MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.aspx), it is in the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly.

> **Namespace:**  System.Web.UI
>   **Assembly:**  System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

Maybe you probably are missing the Assembly reference in your `Web.config` file.
Try creating a brand new web project and compare your `Web.config` files.

Check if you have this in your `Web.config` file `<pages> ==> <controls>` element.

```
<pages>
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp"
             namespace="System.Web.UI"
             assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp"
             namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"
             assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

        <!-- other tag registrations -->
    </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: In my VB project Regrences folder, in visual studio, I didn't have the web.extensions refrenced. Thank you.